# Python telemetry - Log all python modules loaded

Tags: python, ide, jupyter, telemetry

I'm creating a friendly python development environment using venv and pip so users can start a jupyter notebook with all libs they can need on PYTHONPATH.
In order to remove libs not used by users, I want to log all libs loaded during their Python execution in a centralized NAS share (they run their python process on their hosts, but they can write in a central NAS share). To do so, I considered using `strace -e trace=open,read python..` and filter the entries by my libs file path, but I'm pretty sure there should be a standard python lib to do such telemetry job.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could wrap `builtins.__input__` to also log the name of the module imported, then run (via the `exec` function, but we need to catch `if __name__ == '__main__':` blocks so it's likely unavoidable) the code you want to monitor:

`loggy.py`

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3

import builtins
import sys

if __name__ == '__main__':

    builtins.__import_copy__ = builtins.__import__

    __libs = set()

    def __import_wrap__(*args,**kwargs):
        __libs.add(args[0])
        return builtins.__import_copy__(*args,**kwargs)

    builtins.__import__ = __import_wrap__

    sys.argv = sys.argv[1:]

    exec(open(sys.argv[0]).read())

    print(__libs)
```

Test script `test.py`

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3

import re
import sys

if __name__ == '__main__':
    x = re.findall(r'all\w*',sys.argv[1])
    print(x)
```

For me (Python 3.6.9) this seems to work to log all modules imported by the secondary script:

```
mostly@ubuntu:~$ python3 loggy.py test.py "allways misspelling"
['allways']
{'_heapq', 'functools', 'collections.abc', 'operator', 'weakref', 'sys', 'copyreg', '_weakref', 'itertools', '_locale', 'abc', '_collections', 'sre_compile', 'enum', 'sre_parse', '_operator', '_collections_abc', '_bootlocale', '_sre', 'sre_constants', '_thread', 'heapq', 'reprlib', 'keyword', '_functools', 're', 'collections', '_weakrefset', 'builtins', 'types'}
```

Comment: That's perfect. I would add that adding this logic to your main code is enough (no need to call a second python file)

Answer (score 0):

## Problem

Monitor python processes on user python environments/workstations to determine which unused libs to remove.

## Solution

I'm not sure if there's a standalone tool readily available. `strace`(as you mentioned in your question) + `syslog` is an option. I know you mentioned persisting the logs to a NAS, but I would consider also having lightweight `syslog` server as `syslog` can handle edge cases (ie: automatic retries) and provide an interface for you to be able to filter logs.

## References

Syslog Filter Reference: https://www.syslog-ng.com/technical-documents/doc/syslog-ng-open-source-edition/3.17/administration-guide/52#TOPIC-989744

Comment: Hi pygeek

@mostly-harmless solution is exactly what I'm looking for.